# Electron (Atom Shell) severely crashes Windows

Tags: javascript, electron

I am writing an application and running it with Electron. As I am testing and debugging things, I start my application (electron.exe) and close it every so often (sometimes maybe once or twice per minute).

After a (seemingly random and definitely not related to code change) while, the following errors appear right when starting the application:

[image: first errors to appear]

At this point, the application flashes one time when open but then runs normally.

Usually not very long after, starting the application results in the errors below:

[image: second errors to appear]

At this point, the application is frozen for a few seconds when opening and then runs apparently slower than usual. As soon as this starts to happen, it is also impossible to open a browser page (tested Chrome and IE) - page remains blank and process seems to hang:

[image: ie hangs loading google]

The worst is that at this point, Windows will not shut down properly. Trying to sign out or shutdown results in a blue screen with the cursor stuck with the "loading" icon forever. The only solution from there is to force the computer to shut down by holding the power button. When doing this, I had about 50% chance of having Windows stuck in an infinite repair loop, with no other choice than to do a system restore.

So now I learned that I must reboot Windows as soon as those GL_INVALID_OPERATION happen...

Would that be an issue with my computer in particular (I am not able to test on another computer for another 2 weeks) or something with Electron?

Also, on a side note, maybe related or maybe not, sometimes the application seems to start 2 Renderer processes instead of 1 - at least the logs show the "Renderer process started" twice.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a graphics card/driver issue than an electron problem. Sorry mate.

Comment: Looks like it but this computer has never run into any issue like this. It is a rather solid workstation used to running all kind of software, including games and CPU/GPU driven applications. While I agree it could be related to my current hardware/software, it is also clear to me that Electron is causing this to happen (the same application directly in Chrome runs with no problem) and I can't think of releasing my application under Electron to consumers if it can potentially crash people's computer :/

Comment: Windows I've noticed has a lot of problems with Atom/atom components.  It runs much better on Ubuntu.  Not trying to convert you, but if you can drop into Ubuntu for awhile and do the dev work it might help.

Comment: You should probably submit an issue here: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues.

Comment: Just did - thanks for the suggestion.